# AWS SDK for .NET S3 GetPreSignedURL for specific version of versioned object

Tags: .net, sdk, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Has anyone had success populating the versionId of GetPreSignedUrlRequest when building a presigned url using the AmazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL API?
I get AccessDenied back from the browser for the generated URL. 
Its a version enabled bucket and the pre-signed URLs work fine when I omit the versionId from the GetPreSignedUrlRequest.
I'm on current version (Version=1.5.9.0) of the AWS SDK. 
I found a thread from 2010 where AWS stated that this feature was on the roadmap but nothing since.
thanks
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=406987&#406987

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old question, but I came across it while trying to find some answers that I didn't find directly on SO.  GetPreSignedURL does indeed work for retrieving specific versions, but proper use may be a little confusing.

Objects in versioned S3 buckets can have many versions, which can be accessed using `ListObjectVersions`, `GetObjectVersion`, and `GetPresignedURL` (with `VersionId` specified).  The standard object access functions `ListObjects` and `GetObject` only look at the most recent version of the object (the version with `IsLatest` set to true, always returned first from `ListObjectVersions` as far as I can tell).  Some of the object's versions can be "delete markers" (versions with a `Size` of 0 and `IsDeleteMarker` set to true).

Delete markers don't contain object information, so although they appear in the list of object versions, they cannot be "read" by anyone no matter what rights you have.  You'll get an `AccessViolation` of some kind if you try to read a delete marker directly using the SDK and `GetObjectVersion`, and you'll get an `AccessDenied` error when accessing the signed URL if you use `GetPreSignedUrl`.  Object versions appear to always be sorted by time with the most recent versions first.

Objects can have multiple non-delete-marker versions in a row if you write the object multiple times without deletions in between.  Objects can have multiple delete markers if you write an object after it's been deleted and then delete it again.  Objects can even have multiple delete markers in a row (there are probably multiple ways to do this), so you have to be careful how you get the version numbers you want to use, especially when near the end of a listed chunk (you may get a delete marker as the last entry in a list and have to use the continuation token, theoretically even more than once, to get the non-delete-marker version you want).

You have to use different versions for different operations:

- To read a version of the object that's not the latest version (and that will never be the latest version if it's a "deleted" object), you have to skip past the delete markers and newer versions to find the `VersionId` for the non-delete-marker version you want and pass that to `GetObjectVersion` or `GetPresignedURL`.
- To restore a deleted object version (ie. remove it from the trash) you have to get rid of the delete markers that prevent the object from appearing in the normal `ListObject` and `GetObject` calls.  To do this, you have to call `DeleteObjectVersion` (not `RestoreObject`--that's for something else entirely) and pass it the `VersionId` of the delete marker you want to remove.  If there is more than one delete marker in a row (chronologically), you may have to make multiple calls to get the object back to where it's visible through `ListObjects` and `GetObject`.  If it's just delete markers (again there are likely multiple ways to do this), there is nothing to be restored, once you've deleted all the delete markers, there is nothing left anyway. Alternatively, if you want to keep the history of deletions, you could find the version that you want to keep and read the data for that version and write that back to the object, creating a newer version.